# Adding a new contact skips the phonebook, goes to viber

Tags: huawei, viber-messenger

My grandma has a new Huawei phone that has an odd configuration. Whenever she adds a new contact, it doesn't appear in the phonebook, but in Viber instead.
Naturally when she goes to her phonebook looking for her friends and doesn't find them, even though she had added them earlier, she gets very frustrated.

Since she's pretty old, I can't expect her to figure it out on her own. Is there a way to fix this? Viber hijacking your phonebook and not letting you add any contacts is pretty annoying.

Comment: Go into her phone book settings, and make sure *display all contacts* is enabled

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 things to keep in mind:

1. Is your grandma actually going into her phone's contacts to add people, or is she going into the Viber app to add people?
2. When creating contacts, my phone asks me WHERE to store the contacts. In my case, I have 2 options: one the SIM card, or on my Google account. She may have a 3rd option (Viber). She should select one of the other 2. (I recommend Google account).

There is also a setting on Viber to let Viber sync with your phone contacts (so tyhat Viber contacts appear in your phone, and your phone contacts appear in Viber). This should be under [General](https://support.viber.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1354554-personalize-your-viber-settings---android-phones?b_id=3838#general)

Comment: 1. She's going into the phone's contacts. I tried to help her myself, and had the same result, hence why I came here looking for answers.


2. I checked extensively and there were no options to pick where the contacts were saved.

3. I checked the setting to let Viber sync with the phone contacts yesterday, and she let me know that all her Viber contacts appeared in her phone book today, but that seems hacky.